# Minipage are not at same height with textbox

Tags: boxes, minipage, adjustbox

while using `minipage`, in the second column there is a text box. When I've used `fbox` in the second column then the text of the first column goes downward so height not remained same for both sides. Here is the code;

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{Items:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item1
\item Item2
\item Item3
\item Item3
\end{itemize}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Def:}} Cumulative distribution function (cdf ): is the probability that the variable takes a value less than or equal to X.

    \textbf{Items:}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item1 
    \item Item1
    \item Item1
    \item Item1
    \end{itemize}
    \textcolor{red}{\textbf{Def:}}  TCumulative distribution function (cdf ): is the probability that the variable takes a value less than or equa l to X.
    \end{minipage}
    %second column
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \fbox{%
      \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \begin{center}
          Useful mnemonics:
          \begin{itemize}
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \end{itemize}
        \end{center}
      }%
    }

    \end{minipage}
```

and the output of this code is like this; 
[image]

 
 Kindly tell me that how can I arrange them so both columns (or mini-pages) remain at the same height. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a complete example people can compile!

Comment: Is there a `multicols` environment?

Comment: The minipages are aligned using `t` i.e. at the top, but the parbox is aligned using `c` i.e. at the centre. So the centre of the parbox ends up aligned with the top of the first minipage. I think. Also, the content is too wide - you must get bad boxes here - because you have a space between the minipages and no room for the box's line width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\begin{minipage}[T]{0.48\textwidth}
\textbf{Items:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item1
\item Item2
\item Item3
\item Item3
\end{itemize}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Def:}} Cumulative distribution function (cdf ): is the probability that the variable takes a value less than or equal to X.

    \textbf{Items:}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item1 
    \item Item1
    \item Item1
    \item Item1
    \end{itemize}
    \textcolor{red}{\textbf{Def:}}  TCumulative distribution function (cdf ): is the probability that the variable takes a value less than or equa l to X.
    \end{minipage}
    %second column
    \begin{minipage}[T]{0.48\textwidth}
    \fbox{%
      \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \centering
          Useful mnemonics:
          \begin{itemize}
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
          \end{itemize}
      }%
    }
    \end{minipage}
```

Use the `[T]` option for aligning `minipage`s and don't use up all the horizontal space by leaving `0.02\textwidth`, for example `\begin{minipage}[T]{0.48\textwidth}` will be OK.

Answer (score 3):

This aligns the `\parbox...` with the two `minipage` environments and fixes the bad boxes by using `\noindent`, eliminating the space between the `minipage`s and reducing the width of the `\parbox` to allow room for the line and margin of the `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{Items:}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item1
  \item Item2
  \item Item3
  \item Item3
\end{itemize}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Def:}} Cumulative distribution function (cdf ): is the probability that the variable takes a value less than or equal to X.

\textbf{Items:}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item1
  \item Item1
  \item Item1
  \item Item1
\end{itemize}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Def:}}  TCumulative distribution function (cdf ): is the probability that the variable takes a value less than or equa l to X.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\fbox{%
  \parbox[t]{.95\textwidth}{%
    \begin{center}
      Useful mnemonics:
      \begin{itemize}
        \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
        \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
        \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
        \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
        \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
        \item "OIL RIG -- \textbf{O}xidation \textbf{I}s \textbf{L}oss of electrons, \textbf{R}eduction \textbf{I}s \textbf{G}ain of electrons
      \end{itemize}
    \end{center}
  }%
}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned without bad boxes]